# How can I change the amount of time the default screen appears in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, xcode4

How can I change the time the default screen appears in an iPhone app? I am talking about the Default.png image which I have copied in the project but it appears for a longer time then required. How can i change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change that. It's shown until the `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` finishes basically. So if it's on the screen for a long time, then you're probably doing some heavy lifting in there and you should consider doing that on a background thread after the app has launched.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reduce it unfortunately - that is displayed until the [application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] method has returned.  So if you aren't doing anything inside that method, there is no way to help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an NSTimer once the app has loaded to show an UIImageView for a set amount of time and then remove it from the main view. It's not the most elegant of solutions but it'll do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `sleep(time)` in your `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` replacing the time with the number of seconds delay you want in your app.